# React-Select: Stay in edit mode (<input>) after select (enter)

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have an input field for some value and want to use a drop down to display some potential alternatives from which the user can choose if she wants, but is free to add something new.

I have been fighting `react-select` for a while now and I can almost get there but not all the way.

One of my problems is that `react-select` wraps a selection in its own span and positions the input field after that. So if a user wants to edit a selection it can't.

I have been trying to fix `value` to null and manage `inputValue` via a hook and `onInputChange`. That works, but when I set the `inputValue` inside `onChange`, I simply get an empty field. I assume the internal state is ignoring the value of `inputValue` and as I'm keeping 'value` to null, the selected option won't be displayed (expected).

When I try using `creatable` I can't figure out on how to suppress the `Create as ...` menu item. Setting `formatCreateLabel={() => null}` leaves an empty space. I can't find a `component` to override that.

`react-select` is a really powerful module which I obviously try to use outside it's intended use, but I feel I'm really close and just miss something obvious.

Comment: I figured out on how to hide the 'create as ...' item with a bit of hacking of the 'Menu' and 'Option' component override. It's a bit hacky as I 'know' some impementation details (`__isNew__` in the 'create' option).

Comment: could you share your code? I've been trying to remove that as well.